# SmtpClient.Send randomly causes SmtpException 4.7.0 timeout waiting for client input

Tags: c#, .net, exception, exchange-server, smtpclient

I can't seem to find the cause for this problem.

Sometimes I get `SmtpException` "4.7.0 timeout waiting for client input" being thrown on using the following [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) code for [.net-4.0](/questions/tagged/.net-4.0):

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace SendMail
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                string html = "<h1>TEST</h1>";

                using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("sender@domain.com", "receiver@domain.com"))
                {
                    mail.Subject = "Test";
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mail.Body = html;

                    using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("<internal ip address>"))
                    {
                        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("<user name>", "<password>");

                        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                        client.Send(mail);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It usually crashes at the second attempt (i == 1).

I am aware I should create a single `SmtpClient` instance and reuse it in the loop but for the purpose of demonstration and in order to be as close as possible to the real code it has to be this way. While the above isn't quite like my production code it does suffer from the same random problem. I figured that if I could solve the problem with this code then I'd know what to do with my *actual* code, given that it really is a coding issue to begin with. I'm suspecting an obscure server configuration issue but I'm out of ideas on what it could possibly be.

Odd thing: despite being a timeout issue, the exception is thrown very quickly; there's no delay that would suggest an *actual* timing out problem.

The mail server is MS [exchange-server-2007](/questions/tagged/exchange-server-2007) running on [windows-server-2008](/questions/tagged/windows-server-2008) SP2. There's no additional SMTP settings specified in app.config file.

I tried to put the code in a `Do...While` loop that tries five times to send the email back after putting the thread to sleep for one second. Unfortunately that doesn't help: when it fails, it will also fail at the very next attempts.

I also tried using `Thread.Sleep(<delay>)` before every calls to `client.Send(message)` but it made no appearant difference.

Our network admin is adamant on the network running without any issues (no packet drops caused by bad MTU setting or anything like that). He backs this up with the fact that there's only my code that seems to have problems (and he's right) and that it does not only happen on a segment of the network (also right).

It's unlikely that the firewall would be causing this either, as every mail my app sends is using internal addresses.

Anybody has a clue here? It would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I seem to be able to reproduce the problem every time when using default credentials instead:

```
using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("<internal ip address>"))
{
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.Send(mail);
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Nope. Not every time. Everything now works again (until next time).

I really can't put my finger on it.

**UPDATE 3:**

Interesting new development today: I attempted to create a new account inside MS Outlook with the same address I use with Exchange. Only this time instead of adding it as an MS Exchange address I tried setting it up as a POP3/SMTP account. Here is what happened upon testing the connection:

[image: Error reproduced inside MS Outlook]

It's in french but look at the last line: it is the exact same error message I got with my code. This is a clear indication to me that the issue is not within my code.

Of course, this also means that this whole thread shouldn't be on SO. Still, I hope this extra test can help fellow developers out there who are struggling with a similar issue.

Comment: I wonder if Wireshark would show anything.

Comment: @MobyDisk I'm not familiar with Wireshark, or network profiling tools, or even the very idea of monitoring trafic at all, so I can't tell. The one thing I'm sure though is that if it REALLY is a networking issue then it only messes up with my soft and nothing else... which sounds quite unlikely to me. :/ Still, thanks for the hint. Might be something to look at.

Comment: I just reread your issue.  The SmtpClient.Timeout is not relevant here because it is not your SmtpClient timing out, it is the server timing out.  The "timeout waiting for client input" is the server telling you that your side isn't sending anything.  That's odd.  I really do think that using Wireshark or something similar is the only way you will find out.  If you can't see what is being sent, you can't debug it.

Comment: @MobyDisk Is this something that can be solved on the server then? By a setting or something?

Comment: Maybe.  If the server is claiming that you, the client, are not sending data then there isn't much the server can do.  I think you either need to prove the server wrong and them maybe there is some server setting.  Or prove the server right, which means figuring out why the SmtpClient isn't sending anything.  This might be more of an IT problem than a programming problem.  Have you tried sending mail to a different mail server?

Comment: @MobyDisk I did, yes, and it worked. However since the problem occurs randomly it's hard to say it proves anything. The real test would be to use another server for a while, to see if the problem still occurs at the same frequency. The unfortunate thing is that we rely heavily on mailing groups, which we don't have on external, free servers. :s

Comment: I once had a server report that error (or something similar--it's been many years) because I was making too many connections too quickly. The server was throttling me. It would be interesting to see what happens if you put a `Thread.Sleep(5000);` after every message sent.

Comment: I actually tried Thread.Sleep(1000). Might not have been long enough. I might consider trying that again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This definitely sounds like a server or network issue. Reference this serverfault post for instance: https://serverfault.com/questions/344684/exchange-2007-email-error-451-4-7-0-timeout-waiting-for-client-input

It could be a firewall problem if there is a firewall between your machine and the exchange server. A firewall blocks ports between ip addresses, it doesn't matter where the email is going at all. Firewalls are the bane of my programming existence, so definitely ask your net admin if there is a firewall between the servers and have him check if it is working.

It could also be something like a bad NIC (network card) on the server or even a bad cable. Yes, your network admin said the network is rock solid... but never trust network admins. ;)

It could also be a problem with YOUR network card, network settings or ethernet cable, actually.

Have you tried running this from different computers?

Comment: I did try running this from different computers, yes. As I said this doesn't happen on only one segment (as in physical department behind a router/switch). I also agree that it sounds like a server/network issue but if that's the case there should be other mail clients that would suffer from the same problem. Users here runs Outlook all day long without any issues.

Comment: Outlook isn't using SMTP, and most applications are probably catching the error and retrying. I wouldn't expect users to be seeing a problem like this...

Comment: I thought so too and that's why I tried adding a retrying block, but that didn't help. The process would hit the max number of attempts almost immediately. If I just drop the max number parameter it loops endlessly. :s

Comment: If other clients manage to pass through by trying/catching then I'm clueless on how they can do that so efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You can fire if off async like by changing your code as follows. You will need to check the AggregateException to see if something bad happened on any of the executing threads.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        string html = "<h1>TEST</h1>";
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("sender@domain.com", "receiver@domain.com"))
            {
                mail.Subject = "Test";
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Body = html;

                using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("<internal ip address>"))
                {
                    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("<user name>", "<password>");

                    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    client.Send(mail);
                }
            }
        }).ContinueWith(aex => {
            if (aex.Exception != null)
            {
                //add some logic to deal with the exception
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, the problem here is that in some places within my app sending an email is part of a larger process. It's often necessary to know that the mail was successfully sent before letting the process go any further. I therefore cannot allow it to send the email asynchronously, unless I specifically wait for the thread to complete, which seems kinda pointless. :s

Comment: @Crono take a look at some of the properties exposed by client.ServicePoint  -- especially if you can debug and cause the error to happen.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look.

Comment: Yikes... I'm afraid now I can't reproduce the problem anymore. Code runs fine without any timeouts of any kind.

Comment: @Crono that is because I pushed the big red 'Easy' button on my desk.

Comment: I'm sorry I actually meant my original code :). Unfortunately I know it will start over again too soon. And you're lucky, I wish I had that button! :D

Comment: Although I still can't tell if `client.ServicePoint` can reveal anything useful for my case, that's still a thing I've never looked at before. Since I was asking for new ideas, I think you do deserve the bounty because of this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it is better to define SmtpClient before the loop, same problem happened with me and this solved it.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace SendMail
{
    class Program
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("<internal ip address>");

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("<user name>", "<password>");
            //client.EnableSsl = true;
            //client.Port = 25;    
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                string html = "<h1>TEST</h1>";

                using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("sender@domain.com", "receiver@domain.com"))
                {
                    mail.Subject = "Test";
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mail.Body = html;

                    client.Send(mail);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've mentionned that I placed the SmtpClient inside the loop for demonstration purposes. The point I'm trying to make is that the code *should* work regardless that the instance is created inside or outside it.

Comment: @Crono No it should not. When you open and close connections that fast, server gets dizzy and this occurs timeouts from my own experiences. Try a thread sleep for 1sec after each connection close and you will see it works.

Comment: @OğuzSezer I'm sorry but yes it should. First, it's nowhere documented that it won't. Second, it *does* work 99% of the time. Last week I couldn't even manage to reproduce the problem. I changed the code so that it would send a thousand emails and it worked flawlessly. I fully agree that the BEST thing would be to use a single instance IN THIS SCENARIO but I *do* need to figure out why multiple ones sometimes fails in real production code.

Comment: @Crono again, I'm sharing my own experiences by sending over 10millions e-mails a day.

Comment: @OğuzSezer I do appreciate your input but as I already mentioned in the original post comments I *did* try putting the thread to sleep before sending the next email. Unfortunately, it didn't made any difference. Also, I certainly can believe a heavy volume of emails could stress out the server but this isn't what we're doing here. The program sends emails to groups of people (less than 10) less than five times a day (most of the time it's once or twice).

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly new to this messaging issue. I have currently been working on a messaging application and occasionally this exception is thrown into the system.
So far the answers I have picked up on the internet point out that this is an error in the email sender's authentication. Perhaps the limitation of daily submissions and the hourly send limit may inhibit SMTP server authentication of the email. Example, in case smtps.bol.com.br has a limit of 50 emails per hour, having to have a 60 minute interval to send a new batch of messages.
I have done my tests here and I do not have a conclusive answer, but I believe that maybe the way is this. If they find the definitive solution, do not forget to post.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the objects call .Dispose() in all cases.

I saw this problem on a highly active production system that sends 5000+ emails a day, but the problem would only happen to about 5% of the emails.  The code sending the email was written before .Net 4.0, which introduced the Dispose() call to SmtpClient and MailMessage.   I made a very simple change to make sure both objects were disposed and have not seen the problem again in 5 days.

That same code that does NOT call Dispose() runs on less active systems without any problems.  My theory is there is some kind of cumulative resource leak if you fail to call Dispose() and it only causes this error under heavy load.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting similar error couple of years back on Amazon Aws server. It seems my security company "AllCovered.com" had to do a exception to my server ip address to allow send smtp emails.

I do get this error if anytime a new server created is forgotten to be put in exception.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I don't think that helps. We do not create new servers here. :s

Comment: Also the problem appears randomly.